# How do I add my own plugin that I coded into a minecraft server?

Tags: plugins, server, minecraft

Basically I've been coding my own mc plugin and I want to add it to my server. But whenever I try to run the code on it the command doesn't exist so I must have done something wrong in adding the plugin to the server. What I did was make a plugin folder in my mc server folder and put my plugin on there (which is a jar file.) Help me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the wrong server version. Download you're version which your plugin is made and use this as the server. Download [here](https://getbukkit.org/download/spigot)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Spigot? "What I did was I make the plugins folder" that sounds like you are using Minecraft's Server Version, which does not let you use plugins. You should use Spigot/Paper, which can be downloaded from https://getbukkit.org/download/spigot